# Exception 00x8007000B VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I really need some help to start Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I didn't find any solution after searching the internet for this problem. The error appeared using  VS2012 and the problem persisted when I moved to VS2013.

This is the first error I get in the **activityLog.xml**

> SetSite failed for package [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer
>   Package] End package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer
>   Package]

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio? Is that package included by default with it?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition, that package handles the server connection explorer which is at the right side of the development environment. i tried fixing all mysql and ODBC connector but didnt work.